# Login to wordpress with xamarin

Tags: c#, wordpress, xamarin

I'm trying to log into wordpress from a c# xamarin application.

This question is similar and works for me from a standard wpf application: [login to wordpress using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282602/how-to-login-to-wordpress-programmatically) but the classes available in xamarin don't support all the methods required to do this.

I've tried to do this:

```
if (!mLoggedin)
        {
            mLoginCookie = new CookieContainer();
            var clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            clientHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
            clientHandler.CookieContainer = mLoginCookie;
            clientHandler.Proxy = null;

            string loginUri = DOMAIN + "/wp-login.php";

            string reqString = "log=" + mUserName + "&pwd=" + mPassword;
            byte[] requestData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reqString);

            var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);
            var content = new ByteArrayContent(requestData);

            content.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            //content.Headers.Add("User-agent", AGENT);//whines about this!
            content.Headers.Add("Content-length", requestData.Length.ToString());

            var response = client.PostAsync(loginUri, content).Result;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                foreach (Cookie cookie in mLoginCookie.GetCookies(new Uri(DOMAIN)))
                {
                    if (cookie.Name.StartsWith("wordpress_logged_in_"))
                    {
                        mLoggedin = true;
                        return;
                    }
                }
            }
            mLoggedin = false;
        }
```

but I get back a weird error from wp site:

418 unused

## unused

The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.

Please contact the server administrator,
 webmaster@[mysite].com and inform them of the time the error occurred,
and anything you might have done that may have
caused the error.

More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.